# How to target only current hovered element in Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a web page for homework. I am trying to figure out how to make a child div appear whenever I hover over the parent div at the bottom, sort of like a dropdown menu. The thing is that the child div has a class and I want only the element that is hovered to show the child div from the parent div. More specifically, the parent div I am talking about is `<div class="inside-box" onMouseOver="showDDContent();" onMouseOut="hideDDContent();>` and the child div I am talking about is `<div class="dropdown-content">`. I want to use Vanilla Javascript (preferred) or CSS (not preferred).

TLDR: How do I target only current hovered element from HTML/CSS class in Vanilla Javascript?

How do I do that?

I got this far:

**HTML**

```html
<!--Lab 1-->
           <!--Each individual box.-->
           <div class="box">

             <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
             <div class="inside-box" onMouseOver="showDDContent();" onMouseOut="hideDDContent();">

               <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
               <div>
                 <a href="Lab_01/LB1_WeiJianZhen_DD.html">
                     <!--Get an image with 300px width by 200px height. Make it responsive.-->
                     <img src="../../../Visual Content/placeholder.jpg" alt="Under Contruction" class="imgGrids">
                 </a>
               </div>

               <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
               <div class="txtBar">
                   <h3><a href="Lab_01/LB1_WeiJianZhen_DD.html">Lab 1</a></h3>
               </div>

               <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
               <div class="dropdown-content">
                 <p>My first website ever made in an HTML file! Describes a bit about the process of making a very basic website like mine.</p>
               </div>

             <!--End of inside box div.-->
             </div>

           <!--End of box div.-->
           </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
/*Creates the styling of the dropdown box.*/
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #62ff36;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(56, 255, 42, 0.8);
  padding: 12px 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function showDDContent() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content").style.display = "block";
}

function hideDDContent() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Why would you prefer Javascript over a CSS solution? This sounds clearly like a CSS job.

Comment: I agree with connexo, but if you want to go down the the javascript route, you should use `addEventListener` instead of the inline event. You can then use `this` to target the hovered element and then use something like `nextSibling` to select the sibling element that is relevant to the hovered element.

Comment: `.inside-box:hover .dropdown-content { display: block; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest, most performant and overall definitely best way to solve this problem clearly is using **CSS**.

```
.inside-box:hover .dropdown-content { display: block; }
```

---

If for whatever reason you insist go with *Javascript* (which I do explicitly **not recommend**), you are going to have to add 2 listeners to each `.inside-box`, one for `mouseenter`, the other for `mouseleave`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.inside-box').forEach(insideBox => {
  insideBox.addEventListener('mouseenter', () =>  insideBox.querySelector('.dropdown-content').style.display = 'block');
  insideBox.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>  insideBox.querySelector('.dropdown-content').style.display = 'none');
})
```

Using inline event listeners like you suggested is considered very bad practice, so don't try that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, if I add more copies of the divs as in the ones shown above in the HTML section, all of the divs with class="dropdown-content" would display block instead of the one that the cursor is hovered over. Edit: So I want the current div that the mouse is hovered over to show the dropdown. Not  all the divs with class="dropdown".

Comment: *So I want the current div that the mouse is hovered over to show the dropdown. Not all the divs with class="dropdown"* That is exactly what the code in my answer will do. Each `.inside-box` on mouseenter will show its first child element that matches `.dropdown-content`, and on `mouseleave`, hide the same element.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems that I have come to another problem from this answer which I will post later on if I cannot figure it out.